# Mongodb-PHP: What is the query for retriving record of messages with status unread

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am using neatbeans & using mongodb with php for a webapp. I am retriving messages with following command through php.

```
include_once '../lib/mongodb/MongoDbConnector.php';
$mongoDb = new MongoDbConnector();
 $mongoDb = $mongoDb->getConnection();
 $mongoDb = $mongoDb->selectCollection("message");
 $countM = $mongoDb->find(array('client_id' => new MongoId($valueU['_id'])), array('status' => 'unread'));
 $unreadM = $countM->count();
```

The query doesnot work. showing me the data & count of messages who have client_id in it.
What to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is not well formated, it should be like this:

```
$countM = $mongoDb->find(array('client_id' => new MongoId($valueU['_id']), 'status' => 'unread'));
```

Also check if $valueU['_id'] is a string or a mongoID object.

Comment: working!!! but as the find function is used..it shows count as 1 for mongocursor even if the record doesnot match